# Where did the question that I answer disappear to?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I'm pretty sure that I answered a question yesterday regarding a problem with Apache and mod_rewrite (it was an installation/library problem rather than a programming one) on SO - but I can't find any reference to it in my account's activity or when I search for it.

Does this mean that the question has been deleted? Even then - why wouldn't my activity at least reference that I answered it?

Comment: You can find your answer googling for **"how do I go about getting them installed"**. It was deleted by Jeff

Comment: Link to question for 10k+ users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847140/apache-not-working-after-upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly likely that the question was deleted or migrated (answers to migrated questions are automatically deleted *on the original site* though the question remains). Existing answers are (of course) migrated along with the question.

Links to deleted answers aren't included in your profile or recent activity list as they don't contribute anything to your reputation or badges.

Comment: why wouldn't answers to migrated questions be kept? surely they would still be relevant?

Comment: The answers are *also* migrated to the new site. If you have an associated account on the new site, the answer is automatically attributed to you over there.

Comment: ah, okay... but how do I find where the question was migrated to?

Comment: @Horus If it regarded Apache, I'm going to guess ServerFault.

Comment: I'd already looked there in case I'd gotten the two sites mixed up - but can't seem to find it either. *shrugs*

Comment: @Greg - answer updated to make that clear.